# Simple Math on Elasticsearch Query Result

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, kibana-4

Is there any way to do **simple math** on different **elasticsearch query results** in order to visualize it in **kibana**?
for example I want to have something like this in queries:

```
unique_count(Item_ID) - unique_count(Expired_Item_ID)
```

that's difficult especcialy when Item_Id  and Expired_Item_ID are stored in **two different indexes**.

I know there is possibility to write map-reduce job using `scripted metrics` but I hope there is an easier way to do that.

Comment: What do you think about combine multiple aggregation with scripted aggregation? Because there are two way to implement these things. First, compute your data while indexing. Second, compute your data while searching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I need to use second method. because my final kibana dashboard is realtime and I need to do calculations ater the data has indexed (or more data is coming).  
I've tried scripted metric aggregation which is the map-reduce method I mentioned but some simple calculations are difficult to do using map-reduce.
do you know any other script aggregation which can give me for example `unique_count(Item_ID) - unique_count(Expired_Item_ID)` ?

Comment: I don't know which query is give directly this calculation as a result.